# How to check whether .edmx model is using DbContext or ObjectContext in c#

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

How can i programmatically check whether my .edmx entity framework model is using DbContext or ObjectContext in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not your .edmx which use DbContext. The context is generated by the template you choose if you don't use the default generator template.

At runtime, you could check if your context object is a type of DbContext or ObjectContext

```
if(_ctx is DbContext)
{...}
```